# How do I change the image rendered for just one eye?

Tags: google-cardboard

I'm new to  the google cardboard sdk. I need to draw a slightly different image for the left eye as compared to the right(I know distortion correction is taken care of). I saw the "Eye" class spec (an instance of which is passed to OnDrawEye()) from the docs.It does not seem to contain info of which eye is being referred to. How do I tell if the image is being rendered for the right or left eye and code accordingly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the class where you implements the CardboardView.StereoRenderer you have to define the function onDrawEye(), int this function you receive a parameter of type Eye, from that parameter you can know what eye is rendering at the moment with the function getType(). You can check the eye with the constants defined in [Eye.Type](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/android/latest/reference/com/google/vrtoolkit/cardboard/Eye.Type)